# How to avoid sorting and merging colors on stacked barplot in R (ggplot2 or any other)

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, bar-chart

Stacked bar plot always sorts segments on the same bar by fill.    How to avoid that?     What I am trying to achieve is a stacked barplot with alternating blue and red segments (representing state transitions)

Comment: This was probably downvoted because you did not provide a reproducible example (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and an explanation of what you tried. If you do those things, not only will you get more upvotes, any answers you get are much more likely to be useful as answerers will have a better idea what you are asking for!

Answer (score 1):

## Base graphics solution

Use the `col` argument of `barplot`:

```
d <- rep(1, 4)
d <- as.matrix(d, nrow=4, ncol=1)
barplot(d, beside=FALSE, col=c("red", "blue", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

## ggplot solution

```
require(ggplot2)
redBlue <- rep(c("red", "blue"), length(levels(diamonds$color))) 
#redBlue is twice as long as necessary, but that's harmless

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, fill=color)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=redBlue)
```

[image]

Comment: Any such option in GGplot?   Trying d <-data.frame(d)    and ggplot(data=d, mapping=aes(x="foo", y=d, fill=c("red", "blue", "red", "blue"))) + geom_bar()     produces one blue and one red.

Comment: You want `rep(c("red", "blue"), length = length(levels(diamonds$color))`